# How to make request to AWS API Gateway from Postman using temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I followed the steps mentioned in this [repo](https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store) and created an API for users and pets.
I am able to get the temporary credentials after login and signup.
But for "/pets" (both POST and GET), I am getting "Internal Server Error".
I tested the functionality of pets API from AWS API Gateway test interface and was able to create and list pets.

Want to know about the parameters and headers that need to be set in Postman for an authorized request.

Comment: Can you turn on CloudWatch log to see what error you are getting from API Gateway?

Comment: @KaHouIeong I did that and the error which I am getting is "Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function".

Comment: Based on the message, it seems policy attached to your Lambda function is not correct. Make sure you have proper policies configured on Lambda.

Comment: @Nambari thanks the issue was with policy, I got it resolved. A wrong policy was given in the documentation. Added the lambda execution policy for an authorized role.

Comment: Glad it worked. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message ("Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function".), it seems policy attached to your Lambda function is not correct. Make sure you have proper policies configured on Lambda